# UTF-8 characters usage in python3.4 script is throwing SyntaxError. How to use it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8

I am trying execute following lines of code in  python3.4:

```
user ="ŠŒŽ‡†ƒ€‰"
print(user)
```

But the above user initialization line is resulting in following error:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8a in position 0: invalid start byte
```

I want to use the same user in authentication later. 
How to use UTF-8 characters in python3.4 script ?

Comment: I can't replicate this.

Comment: Is your EDITOR saving in UTF-8?

Comment: @Max: Yes. Copied the same code to notepad and saved as utf-8. Tried to execute it. It is resulting in the following:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_1.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(user)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-4: cha
racter maps to <undefined>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your file is not actually saved in UTF-8.  Assuming that the syntax error is occurring on the first non-ASCII character (`Š`), the file is most likely encoded in [Windows 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), which encodes that character as 0x8A.  If you wish to continue using this encoding, add this line to the top of your Python file:

```
# -*- coding: windows-1252 -*-
```

Comment: @C8H10N4O2: Declaring the encoding as UTF-8 will only work if the file actually *is* in UTF-8.